# Como o websocket funciona no php

Tags: php, websocket

Eu tenho essa dúvida, por exemplo, eu tenho um servidor escrito em PHP.

Quando um usuário `A` se conecta a esse servidor o servidor executa uma ação que leva 4 segundos por exemplo, se antes desse prazo um novo usuário `B` se conectar, ele terá que esperar a execução do usuário `A` acabar antes de fazer sua execução? ou como funciona? estou perdido.

Não sei se me fiz entender..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### WebSocket

Em websockets o processo é bastante semelhante ao HTTP normal, mas a diferença é que não fechamos a conexão e não precisamos requisitar o servidor novamente pra saber quando existe algo novo, o evento dentro `ws` recebe sinais ou dados diretamente do servidor.

Se escrever um *websocket* básico provavelmente ele será síncrono, se o usuário `A` enviar algo muito longo provavelmente o processo ficará "parado" até terminar, mas no momento de enviar pros demais usuários a longa mensagem do usuário `A` todos receberão ao mesmo tempo provavelmente.

No entanto ao ler sobre o [`ratchetphp/Ratchet`](https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet/issues/214), mais especificamente a esta mensagem:

- https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet/issues/214#issuecomment-49737414

  Ele afirma que o `Ratchet` é assíncrono e indica dois links. Se você olhar o repositório https://github.com/reactphp/socket verá a seguinte descrição:

  > Asynchronous socket server (pt: *Servidor socket assíncrono*)

Também no link indicado no comentário do github, existe a opção de usar "processo filhos":

- https://github.com/reactphp/child-process)

  E lá no repositório está a seguinte descrição:

  > Asynchronous ChildProcess (pt: Processo filhos assíncronos)

  Exemplo de uso:

  ```
  $loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();

  $process = new React\ChildProcess\Process('echo foo');

  $process->on('exit', function($exitCode, $termSignal) {
      // ...
  });

  $loop->addTimer(0.001, function($timer) use ($process) {
      $process->start($timer->getLoop());

      $process->stdout->on('data', function($output) {
          // ...
      });
  });

  $loop->run();
  ```

**Resumindo:** Então como os websockets funcionam no PHP vai depender de como o código foi escrito, o `reactphp` já é assíncrono e ainda suporta `child-process`, então usando bem a biblioteca, o usuário `B` não vai precisar esperar o usuário `A` pra poder interagir com o websocket.

<s>Um *socket* dentro do php funciona muito parecido com um socket normal, geralmente usamos o `fsockopen` ou `stream`, ou até mesmo outras bibliotecas como `curl`.</s>

O PHP é escrito em C++, portanto provavelmente vai depender de qual extensão do php você se refere. Mas o básico é ele se conecta por um socket, vai depender de você como desenvolvedor definir, por exemplo pra fazer um requisição HTTP é necessário fazer um requisição por TCP.

---

### Servidores HTTP

Mas se o que você quer entender é como funciona o gerenciamento de requisições de clientes a um servidor "normal" que usa PHP (servido de produção), devo lhe dizer que não é o php que gerencia isto, mas sim o [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org) ou [Nginx](http://nginx.org) ou [lightTPD](https://www.lighttpd.net), que são servidores HTTP.

- Note que o PHP é o back-end do servidor HTTP, assim como ao invés de PHP, pode-se usar Python ou outras interpretadores/compiladores, sendo assim o PHP responde ao servidor HTTP e este mesmo servidor é que responde ao cliente (navegador do usuário).

Tanto Apache quanto os outros servidores dividem as requisições por `childs` (que são uma espécie de "thread"), no apache o processo é síncrono mas ainda sim possui vários childs o que possibilita várias pessoas acessarem sem precisar que uma espere a outra. É possível configurar limites no próprio Apache, lembre-se quanto maior o limite mais memória será necessário.

Já os servidores Ngnix e lightTPD dizem ser assíncronos, o que provavelmente divide de uma maneira diferente os `childs` e possibilita um maior numero de usuários acessarem ao mesmo tempo, mas ainda sim é usado estes `childs`.

O childs são como threads ou subprocessos, as conexões provavelmente são dividas entre estes subprocessos e devolvidas posteriormente.

Cada tipo de servidor tem a sua maneira de gerenciar as conexões e devolver a resposta das requisições, isto também pode variar com o tipo de servidor, como um servidor que use kernel Linux ou um servidor baseado em Windows.

Mas no básico o usuário `B` não precisa esperar o `A` acabar a sua execução.

Comment: Então a cada conexão ou requisição aquele socket é aberto um thread para o processamento do mesmo? (poderia me ajudar no chat em outra questão?)

Comment: Sim! Mas na minha opinião essa descrição se aplica mais às requisições http normais; websocket já é um mundo totalmente diferente. Esse seu servidor websocket deve ser 100% PHP não? Se for ele deve ter algo semelhante à um "loop de mensagens" que recebe e processa as requisições; dependendo de como isso foi feito ele só vai processar uma requisição de cada vez.

Comment: @PerryWerneck uso ratcher para manusear os sockets, ele é assíncrono. Não sei se isso interfere.

Comment: @user3163662 Não conhecia essa ratchet (boa dica!) mas pesquisando um pouco achei uma pergunta sobre uso de multiplas threads nele aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25704251/using-php-pthreads-with-ratchet-websocket

Comment: @user3163662 editei a resposta, acho que agora ficou claro pra mim a sua pergunta.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento supondo que eu usasse um servidor comum, sem ser assíncrono, e o usuário `A` estivesse realizando um processo de 1 minuto, então o usuário `B` seria obrigado a esperar esse 1 minuto, certo? só pra confirmar.

Comment: @user3163662 servidor comum você se refere ao Apache, Ngnix ou lighttpd? Se for não irá precisar, pois todos usam `childs`. Se você estiver falando de um websocket bem simples, então vai depender de como foi escrito, supondo que seja sincrono e o processo do lado back-end for demorar 1 minuto provavelmente terão sim que esperar. Foi como eu disse vai depender de como foi escrito. Resumindo como eu disse na resposta: websocket em php vai depender de como foi escrito e servidores http comuns usam childs, o que faz ninguem a maioria não ter que esperar (é configuravel). :)

Comment: Obrigado!!! Feliz natal!

Comment: Esse `Ratchet` é muito complicado de implementar. Já tentei uma vez, mas não consegui. Talvez eu tente novamente quando precisar usar WebSockets. Parabéns pela resposta

Comment: Obrigado @TheProHands, gostaria de tentar lhe ajudar, me diga, a sua dificuldade é no composer ou em rodar o websocket em um servidor shared ou VPS?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Não consigo me lembrar muito bem! Um dia (quase 4 meses atrás) eu estava tentando implementar o Ratchet, mas parece que um erro era jogado. A maneira que eu estava fazendo essa implementação parecia meio estreita, obviamente por isso não funcionaria. Ah! E eu estava tentando rodar a WebSocket no `localhost:8080` para ver se funcionava. Na verdade nunca consegui usar WebSockets :/ . Já tentei usar servidores online também, mas não funcionou (tipo esse: https://www.websocket.org/echo.html). Quando eu uso servidores online a WebSocket não manda mensagem para a outra janela.

Comment: @TheProHands parece um erro especifico, se voltar a tentar faze-lo e tiver dificuldade pode fazer uma pergunta no site que tentarei ajudar, até mais ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento o Apache fica responsável por gerenciar a parte de WebSocket também ou seria o próprio PHP?

Comment: @gato o apache não tem relação alguma com WebSockets, os websockets são rodados a parte, geralmente usam uma porta propria e na maioria dos casos o proprio PHP cria o socket a porta ou dados são repassados via uma PORTA no servidor ou um proxy-reverso. Se a hospedagem não tiver suporte para isto (geralmente hospedagens comuns não tem) então será impossivel startar um websocket.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento você pode tirar uma dúvida minha? Eu te mandei uma mensagem no skype mas naõ tive retorno.