# WebSocket Html5 e Php?

Tags: php, javascript, websocket

surgiu um interesse de conhecimento aqui para fazer aplicações em tempo real.

Vi aqui diversos artigos porém esta dando "pal" na url que passo no js

Estou passando da seguinte forma:

`var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8000');`

Uso xampp.

**Porém não sou perito em WebSocket, queria saber se alguem pode me auxiliar do zero com algum post que ensina bem ou por aqui mesmo explicando passo a passo. Queria muito saber como usar, agradeço desde já.**

Comment: Alguém pode ensinar WebSocket? kkkk

Comment: Para mim o servidor é o maior problema... por isso nunca consegui usar uma *ws* nem ao *mínimo* no localhost.

Comment: Confira este [tutorial aqui](http://www.phpbuilder.com/articles/application-architecture/optimization/creating-real-time-applications-with-php-and-websockets.html), muito bem explicado sobre o assunto.

Comment: [aqui tem um prontinho](https://github.com/nekudo/php-websocket) para você usar.

Comment: [aqui tem uma boa explicação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105422/como-o-websocket-funciona-no-php), veja se te ajuda.

Comment: Como eu faria pra preparar meu php pra um WebSocket?

Comment: ahh, muito obrigado pela ajuda ai pessoal. Agradecendo desde já