# Checar mudanças no banco de dados de forma correta

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, query

Preciso checar mudanças no meu banco de dados e criei um script que envia requisições a cada milissegundo chamando uma função que retorna o numero de linhas nesse banco de dados, porém percebi que é uma forma bem errada de se fazer isso pois deixa meu sistema pesado e com minha hospedagem de teste se esgota o limite de consultas ao banco de dados em pouco tempo. Existe outra forma de realizar a atualização em tempo real do numero de linhas na tabela do banco de dados sem enviar diversas requisições de checagem ?

Minha função php:

```html
switch ($acao) {


case 'quantia':
$PDO = conectar();
            $SG = $PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM telas");
            $SG->execute();
            $result = $SG->fetchAll();
            $bata = count($result);
echo $bata;
break;
```

Js que executa o looping:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 
function checar() { 
$.ajax({
method: "POST",
dataType: 'html',
url: "functions/checagem.php",
data: 'acao=quantia',
success: function(resultado){ $('#oi').html(resultado); }

})
}

setInterval("checar()", 1)

</script>
```

Comment: Acredito que você precise de WebSockets para seguir com a sua implementação, onde o servidor irá notificar o cliente sobre mudanças

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realmente. Enviar uma requisição a cada milissegundo é algo errado, até mesmo absurdo de se fazer em uma aplicação real.

É recomendado, então que você use uma nova tecnologia denominada ***WebSockets***. Você pode verificar mais sobre elas nos links a seguir:

- [Como o websocket funciona no php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105422/como-o-websocket-funciona-no-php)
- [Uma boa biblioteca para se trabalhar com websockets em php](http://socketo.me/)

No entanto, existem linguagens melhores que php para se trabalhar com WebSockets, como JavaScript, usando **NodeJS**.